# How to get access token with anonymous user account using Microsoft graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my .NET `MVC` project, if a user login in the system, he will get his email and system will send a welcome email later.

My problem is that I don't want every user to login and go through authorization process to get his personal information, such as email, username.

With above condition in mind, after research I found out Microsoft graph can help me with my situation. However I'm not sure where to dig in.

Can anyone give help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) we can get an Access Token from some background services or daemons.

Based on my test, we can try the following steps:
First, we should get administrator consent:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                                           {
                                               ClientId = clientId,
                                               Authority = authority,
                                               RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                                               PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                                               Scope = "openid profile",
                                               ResponseType = "id_token",
                                               TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false, NameClaimType = "name" },
                                               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                                               {
                                                                   AuthenticationFailed = this.OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                                                                   SecurityTokenValidated = this.OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync
                                                               }
                                           });

ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.clientId, string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId), Startup.redirectUri,
                                                                                       new ClientCredential(Startup.clientSecret), null, appTokenCache.GetMsalCacheInstance());
AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { MSGraphScope });
```

Second, we can get the user by the email from the url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email address}`. For example,`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx.outlook.com`

Then, we can use the API like this: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{user id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail`, For this, we can refer to [Send mail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail)

For more details, we can download the simple from  [v2.0 daemon sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2) on GitHub.